# rviz "Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException)"

Tags: rviz, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a weird problem running rviz. It was working perfectly fine until something (I do not know what) happened. Now I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] [1333511095.207674058]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
```

I tried the solution [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11148/rviz-in-ros-electric?answer=16630#post-id-16630).
This is what I get from `glxinfo | grep version`

```
server glx version string: 1.2
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.7.1)
```

And `ldd bin/rviz |grep GL`

```
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x01252000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x1d630000)
```

And `ls -l /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2010-09-15 16:10 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2
```

The weird thing is, sometimes rviz works after I restart the computer. Sometimes it doesn't. I do remember there is an extra "OpenGL shading version" occasionally when I do glxinfo. I'm not sure if that is the issue?

EDIT:
And it gets weirder: I can run rviz in the terminal that shows the "shading version". But not in the terminal that doesn't. Why one terminal would show "shading version" and not the other is something I do not understand as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31146/rviz-%22caught-exception-while-loading:-ogre-exception(3:renderingapiexception)%22/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was caused by compiz. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/desktop-effects/+bug/137388)

Bottomline:
Don't use Ctrl-Alt-T to open a new terminal if you need to run rviz. Otherwise you'll need to `unset LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT`

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0